# SQL Query, use MAX function or equivalent

Tags: php, sql

Here is my problem, I have this request (it works) but I would like to replace the `TO_DAYS(notification.created_at)` by the latest action of the user.

I tried to use `TO_DAYS(MAX(notification.created_at))` but it returns `"#1111 - Invalid use of group function"`.

```
SELECT user.email, notification.type, max(notification.created_at) AS date 
    FROM user, notification 
    WHERE (user.id = notification.user_id) AND (TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(notification.created_at) >= 30)
    GROUP BY user.id 
    ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Comment: This is because when using `GROUP BY` you have to group by all the columns that are in `SELECT` part...

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean 5.1?

Comment: @shadyyx When i try to make `GROUP BY user.id, user.email, notification.type, notification.created_at` it returns the same error...

Comment: If I recall correctly, you have to use HAVING instead of WHERE to be able to use MAX

Comment: @PhilipiWillemann Thanks it works. Please write an answer and I will validate it. ;) I can't validate comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using aggregate functions like MAX, you have to use HAVING and not WHERE, it's possible to use both on the same command, however HAVING will always come after WHERE and GROUP BY.

for more info : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Answer (score 1):

First of all I do not understand why not using `LEFT JOIN` in Your query...
Secondly it should be enough to convert to days the subtraction itself...
Thirdly, that condition from `WHERE` should go into `HAVING`...
Fourthly, I guess that `date` in `SELECT` should also be escaped...
It could be:

```sql
SELECT u.email, n.type, max(n.created_at) AS `date`
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN notification n ON u.id = n.user_id
GROUP BY user.id 
HAVING TO_DAYS(NOW() - MAX(n.created_at)) >= 30
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Try this one...

Comment: It works, thanks but I followed Philipi Willemann's advice.
Thanks.